# Is permission level affecting Excel links from updating?

Tags: excel

I have some Excel documents on a Sharepoint site.  I added some links to other Excel documents on a network drive.  When I open the Excel files on the Sharepoint directory, they update just fine.  When other users open those files, they don't update the links.

info that may or may not be relevant:

- My permission level is "Full Control, Limited Access"
- The users with problems have a permission level of "Read"
- I created the links myself
- The source of the links are Excel files on a secured network, but the users experiencing problems have complete access to those Excel files and directories.
- I have experimented with having the Excel links update with a notification prompt and also to update the links automatically, to no avail

Is the "Read" permission level too low to update links in Excel?  Is updating links considered an edit function of sorts, and if so, what level access would they require?

Answer (score 0):

Read is too low, they will need Contribute permission level or a custom permission level that includes editing items to be able to modify the files.